# Flash/AS3 highlighting Arabic text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, uitextfield, highlight, arabic

Whenever I try to highlight Arabic text, it starts to go really weird and highlights at wrong parts.

Try it out for yourself to see what I mean: http://www.fastswf.com/iJ_P74c

Try highlighting the Arabic text and notice how weird things happen, Then highlight the English sentence and you'll notice that it's perfectly normal.

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit: If it's important; the font used is Times New Roman; Device Fonts; Regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of mixing RTL and LTR languages in the same text field, 'Classic Text` as Adobe calls it versus 'FTL text'.

Use [TLFTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) instead of [UITextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UITextField.html) and text highlighting for mixed RTL and LTR languages in the same text block will be handled correctly.

[TLF text provides the following enhancements over Classic text:](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/text-layout-framework-tlf-text.html)

- The ability to create right-to-left text for Arabic and Hebrew scripts.
- **Support for bi-directional text, where right-to-left text can contain elements of left-to-right text. This is important for embedding English words or Arabic numerals within Arabic/Hebrew text, for example**
- Print-quality typography.
- Additional character styles, including leading, ligatures, highlight color, underline, strikethrough, case, digit case, and more.
- Additional paragraph styles, including multi-column support with gutter width, last line justification options, margins, indents, paragraph spacing, and container padding values.
- Control of additional Asian text attributes, including Tate Chu Yoko, Mojikumi, Kinsoku Shori Type, and Leading model.
- You can apply attributes such as 3D Rotation, Color Effects, and Blend Modes to TLF text without placing it in a movie clip symbol.
- Text can flow across multiple text containers. These containers are called threaded or linked text containers.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot!

I've got a question though... Ever since I swapped to TLF, the program's loading time took a lot longer and it all looks noticeably slower....Is this normal? Again, thanks :)

Comment: "noticeably slower"... The TFL control is a 'fat' memory control as it does a LOT in regards to text processing, but I normally only had one or two in an app being displayed at the same time (on the stage) as I used TFL to format the entire page (covering most of the stage). Never noticed a slow down in that regard.

Comment: Well, I Swapped 1 Textbox to TLF and it all suddenly went slower... But I guess it doesn't really matter too much. Only the loading times are longer. Thanks a lot for all your help ^-^